# Does attribute node exist in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone give me an example of attribute node in HTML, whose `nodeType` value will be 2? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All attribute nodes must have a type of 2, as that is what `document.ATTRIBUTE_NODE` is defined to.

See [MDN documentation on `Attr` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr):

> **`nodeType`**
>   This property now always returns 2 (`ATTRIBUTE_NODE`).

Generalized example:

```js
var attr = document.getElementById('tistheid').attributes[1]
document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = document.ATTRIBUTE_NODE

var output = document.getElementById('output')
output.innerHTML =        'constructor:\t' + attr.constructor.name
                 + '\n' + 'type:\t'        + attr.nodeType
                 + '\n' + 'value:\t'       + attr.value
```

```html
<p id="tistheid" class="tistheclass"></p>
<p>
  This is the value of ATTRIBUTE_NODE: <span id="num"></span>
</p>
<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

Despite an attempt by browser vendors and standardization organizations to make `Attr` no longer inherit from `Node` in the past, they eventually decided to keep `Node` in the `Attr` inheritance chain, due to compatibility concerns with older websites. However, as a developer now one should avoid using methods inherited from `Node` on an `Attr`.

*Edit (2017-08-09): WHATWG has made `Attr` inherit from `Node` again. Update accordingly.*

Comment: @JenniferMassey, do you mind [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) by pressing the checkmark above? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get a node of `nodeType` value of 2 with `Element.getAttributeNode()`

Per: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr

> This type represents a DOM element's attribute as an object. In most
>   DOM methods, you will probably directly retrieve the attribute as a
>   string (e.g., Element.getAttribute(), but certain functions (e.g.,
>   Element.getAttributeNode()) or means of iterating give Attr types.

This type also appears to be deprecated per: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Answer (score 0):

See Below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="myP" class="buttonClass">Click the button to get the node type of this element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myP").getAttributeNode("class").nodeType;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very cool. Can you explain why getElementById("myP").nodeType doesn't work?

Comment: document.getElementById("myP").nodeType will work and the output will be 1. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_nodetype